# couldn't catch the updated value in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I ran two ajax one for post and one for get

This one is for posting form values by serialize.

```
  $(function(){
    function showValues() {
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data:  $( "form" ).serialize(),

        success: function(data){
          var x = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['q10']); ?>;
          console.log(x);
        }
      });
    }
    $( "input[type='checkbox'], input[type='radio']" ).on( "click", showValues );
    $( "select" ).on( "change", showValues );
    showValues(); 
  });
```

and I store the values in variable

```
if(isset($_POST['q10']))
{
  if($_POST['q10'] == 2){
    $_SESSION['q10']=1;        
  }else{
    $_SESSION['q10']=0;
  }
}
```

then i use another ajax for catching the updated values but it gives me the old values

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $("#result").click(function(){

            $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              success: function(res) {

                var session = <?php echo(json_encode($page_session)); ?>;    
                if(session == 1){

                  document.getElementById("s1").style.display="block";
                  document.getElementById("s1").textContent = <?php echo(json_encode($_SESSION['q1'])); ?> ;
                }
              }
           });
       });
 });
```

Comment: get parameters are strings, arent they?

Comment: PHP is server-side. JS is (in your case) client-side.Your php code insertions inside your JS are only interpreted once, before the page is served to your browser. Not when you do an Ajax request. You need to use the `data` and `res` responses you get from the server, using JS. Right now, you're doing Ajax requests, but not even using the results.